# How to Get a pointer to MFC Ribbon ComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm developing an **MFC Ribbon application** on visual studio 2013 and I'm new in MFC developement.
I've added **MFC Ribbon ComboBox** from designer window. Now, ***I want to add data runtime into MFC Ribbon ComboBox***, I've done google & read **MSDN** as well as **Code Project** example regarding MFC Ribbon. but, I was unable to figured how to get pointer to combobox and add data into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CMFCRibbonBar::FindByID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984395.aspx). So, something like this:

```
CMFCRibbonComboBox *pCombo = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonComboBox,
                                      m_wndRibbonBar.FindByID(ID_COMBO1));
```

The ID you use (in the above example `ID_COMBO1`) is the ID you gave it in the Properties window in the ribbon designer, and `m_wndRibbonBar` is the member variable of the ribbon itself, which is usually auto-generated in your `CMainFrm` class.